# Check if value exists in dataframe (of different length) and replace

Tags: r, function, compare, dataframe, subset

EDIT

I have the two dataframes of different length:

```
kframe <- data.frame(One=c("NO123","NO234", "NO345", "NO432"),Two=c("NAME1","NAME2","NAME3","NAME4"), Three=c(1,2,3,4))
lframe <- data.frame(One=c("NO123","NO587", "NO345"),Two=c("N1","N2","N2"), Three=c(2,3,4))
```

Would like to check if values in `lframe$One[x]` (with `x=1:nrow(lframe)`) exists in `kframe$One`, and if true replace the value in `lframe$Two[x]`, else do nothing..

How to do this?

Edit:

Or, to put in another way: If true, add the values in $Three...

Expected outcome:

lframe:

```
  One   Two  Three
1 NO123 NAME1 3
2 NO587 N2    3
3 NO345 NAME3 7
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you expect to see as the output for these two small `data.frame`s?

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Your comment to the answer below makes it even less clear.

Comment: sorry, new to both R and stackoverflow

Comment: @Fred Do you want to replace lframe$Two by kframe$Two when lframe$One match with kframe$One?

Comment: @agstudy: yes (a loop from 1 to nrow(lframe) example: lframe$One[1] matches any of the values in kframe$One, in this case kframe$One[1], then lframe$Two[1] <- kframe$Two[1], next lframe$One[2] matches any if the values in kframe$One, in this case non, then lframe$Two[1] is still the same, and so on...)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(kframe)) {
   if (lframe$One[i] == kframe$One[i]) {
      lframe$Two[i] <- kframe$Two[i]
   }
}
```

Comment: This is inefficient, it also won't work with factor columns with differing levels